# Beyond the second derivative in the study of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, self-learning, elementary-functions

I was wondering about the analysis of derivatives in the study of a function. We know that

- $f'(x) = 0$ can give us the critical points $x_k$ (maximum, minimum and sometimes inflection points), not always but it's not the point.
- $f'(x) > 0$ lead us to find the intervals in which the function is increasing or decreasing.
- $f''(x_k)$ can be useful to classify the critical points as maximum, minimum or inflection points.
- $f''(x) = 0$ gives us the inflection points.
- $f''(x) > 0$ lead us to find the interval in which the function is concave or convex.

Now my question is: is there some useful/interesting reason to study the derivatives beyond the second one?

I mean what could $$f'''(x) = 0$$ give us? What kind of points, if any?

And what $$f'''(x) > 0$$ could give us in terms of intervals?

(Clearly my question is related to those functions that can admit/have a third, or higher, derivative).

Comment: [This](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Higher_derivative_test) might be of interest to you.

Comment: 3-d derivative is 1-st for 2-d and 2-d for 1-st. This idea works on every step upper.